# Adssense auto ads CLS issue

Tags: html, css, adsense, core-web-vitals

My Site theme optimize for Core Web Vital and has no problem in search console,
since I enabled Adsense on my site, I get CLS issue (more than 0.25 (mobile)) in webmaster tools.

I try to figure it out how to solve the problem, I found that it might because of Auto Ads enable. when Auto ads enabled there is no fixed height for ads so when ads load we can see a shift in content and that might be the problem.
I try to add height with CSS but does' work.

**Can I fix this problem without disabling Auto Ads?**

Site: https://hexrom.com/

[image: screenshot of auto ads]

Comment: How do you confirm it is autoads causing the CLS?

Answer (score 0):

You could fix height of the auto ads from CSS.

```
.google-auto-placed {
  height: 200px;
}
```